# Nightmare iterating inside loop

Tags: javascript, electron, nightmare

I have following code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
    DoIt();
    console.log(i);
}

function DoIt(){
    var nightmare = Nightmare({
        electronPath: require('./node_modules/electron'),
        openDevTools:{
            mode: 'detach'
        },
        show: true
    });
    nightmare
        .goto('http://google.com')
        .end(()=>{
            return true;
        })
}
```

I am rugging this inside electron app. However this executes async and I am getting instantly output in console (0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and nightmare opens all 10 windows at same time!

How to execute following code synchorous? 
I'd like to get following result:

do while counter < value(e.g. 10)

1) counter = 0

2) nighmare work

3) nightmare end, counter++

---

1) counter = 1

2) nightmare work

3) nightmare end, counter++

e.t.c.

Comment: `await nightmare`, Anyway, don't add a catch to your test, as that will mean the test will always pass, which would make it useless, which basically means you might as well not write any tests.

Comment: without catch function, nightmare wont run :( I tried already

Comment: Then you know either your test is wrong, or your code is wrong. But in this case, likely the test. You tell it to load a page and then click on a button, without waiting for the page to be loaded.
-
You just removed your code, which is not really the SO standard, but add a `wait('button-selector')`before you click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this instead or for-loop:

```
(function iteration(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    DoIt(i).then(() => iteration(i + 1))
  }
})(0)
```

For this make sure `DoIt` returns Promise:

```
function DoIt(index) {
  var nightmare = Nightmare({
    electronPath: require('./node_modules/electron'),
    openDevTools: {
      mode: 'detach'
    },
    show: true
  });

  return nightmare
    .goto('http://google.com')
    .end(() => {
      return true;
    })
}
```

Comment: Works like Charm!
Btw, could it be possible working with my 'for' loop cycle? How?

Comment: No, you can't work with for-loop, because it doesn't wait for previous iteration to finish.

Comment: could you please also explain how to understand when to use promise? I didnt find about promises at nightmare github guide

Comment: alright, so, Promise based function should iterate like recursion?

Comment: Yes, it's is recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

ES2017: You can wrap the async code inside a function, returning a promise( Nightmare returns promise).

Then call the functioninside the for loop but with the magical Await keyword. :)

```js
function DoIt(i) {
  const Nightmare = require("nightmare");
  var nightmare = Nightmare({
    openDevTools: {
      mode: "detach"
    },
    show: true
  });

  return nightmare.goto("http://google.com").end(() => {
    return true;
  });
}

(async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    await DoIt(i);
  }
})();
```